# How to solve the warning: "possible loss of data due to type conversion" in MQL5

Tags: type-conversion, compiler-warnings, algorithmic-trading, mql5, metatrader5

I wrote this sample code for learning purposes but I can't seem to solve the warning message of "**possible loss of data due to type conversion**".

I have tried to search online but I can't seem to find a solution on how to pass the value of the MQL5 built-in functions without getting this warning.

The `iAMA` built-in function of MQL5 returns an integer and this integer is getting assigned to a variable of type integer (as shown in the sample code below). I am not sure why there is a **data loss warning** if both of them are integers.

**Note:** The code is compiling and running well but for educational purposes, I would like to understand how to solve this warning message.

Your help will be much appreciated!

**Here is the code:**

```
// --- Information Properties
#property description "Adaptive Moving Average Function Test"

//--- Core Properties
#property indicator_chart_window
#property indicator_buffers 1
#property indicator_plots   1

// --- Styling & Labels Properties
#property indicator_type1   DRAW_LINE
#property indicator_color1  clrBlack
#property indicator_width1  2
#property indicator_label1  "Adaptive Moving Average"

//--- Constant Variables
const int ama_period  = 34;
const int ama_fast_ma = 2;
const int ama_slow_ma = 34;

//--- Global Variables
double ama_src = PRICE_MEDIAN;

//--- Buffers
double ama_buffer[];

//--- Handles
int ama_buffer_handle;

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Indicator Initialization                                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

int OnInit()
{
//--- Buffers Assignment
    SetIndexBuffer(0, ama_buffer, INDICATOR_DATA);

//--- Accuracy Setting
    IndicatorSetInteger(INDICATOR_DIGITS, _Digits);

//--- First Bar Setting
    PlotIndexSetInteger(0, PLOT_DRAW_BEGIN, ama_period - 1);

//--- Line Shifts Calculations
    PlotIndexSetInteger(0, PLOT_SHIFT, 0);

//--- Labels Calculations
    PlotIndexSetString(0, PLOT_LABEL, "AMA");

//--- Handles Calculations
    ama_buffer_handle = iAMA(NULL, 0, ama_period, ama_fast_ma, ama_slow_ma, 0, ama_src);

    return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|  OnCalculate function                                            |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
                const double &close[],
                const long &tick_volume[],
                const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[])
{
    if(rates_total < ama_period)
    {
        return(0);
    }

//--- Troubleshooting: Data Calculation
    int calculated = BarsCalculated(ama_buffer_handle);
    if(calculated < rates_total)
    {
        Print("Not all data of ama_buffer_handle is calculated (", calculated, " bars). Error ", GetLastError());
        return(0);
    }

//--- Troubleshooting: Data Copying
    int to_copy;
    if(prev_calculated > rates_total || prev_calculated < 0)
    {
        to_copy = rates_total;
    }
    else
    {
        to_copy = rates_total - prev_calculated;
        if(prev_calculated > 0)
        {
            to_copy++;
        }
    }

//--- Copy & Validate Buffers
    if(CopyBuffer(ama_buffer_handle, 0, 0, to_copy, ama_buffer) <= 0)
    {
        Print("getting ama_buffer_handle is failed! Error ", GetLastError());
        return(0);
    }
  
    if(IsStopped())
    {
        return(0);
    }

    return(rates_total);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing back the documentation, I found out that I need to pass an `ENUM_APPLIED_PRICE` to the `iAMA` function instead of a `double` variable. That resolves the problem.

As in: `ENUM_APPLIED_PRICE ama_src = PRICE_MEDIAN;`

Answer (score 0):

You should Flag your own Answer as solved,
to be fair for everybody.

Thank you.